# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I updated my project Laravel version from 5.1 to 5.7 and found the error:

> "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()"

And in the same error screen:

> "A facade root has not been set."

I don't know what's wrong. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in the `config/app.php' file:

Provider

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
```

Facade

```
'aliases' => [
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
```